# How to get form fields' id in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Is there any way to get the id of a field in a template?

In the HTML I get: `<input name="field_name" id="id_field_name"...`

I know I can get the name with `{{ field.html_name }}`, but is there anything similar for getting the id?
Or can I only get it like this: `id_{{ field.html_name }}`?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

You can get the ID like this:

```
{{ field.auto_id }}
```

Comment: what about field name?

Comment: @Clayton `{{ field.html_name }}`

Answer (score 36):

You can also use [`id_for_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label):

```
{{ field.id_for_label }}
```

Answer (score 13):

This doesn't work for every form field.

For instance `{{ form.address.auto_id }}` works while `{{ form.address.auto_name }}` will not.

However you can use `{{ form.address.html_name }}` to get the equivalent answer.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

Comment: I think what you mean is that you can use "auto_id" for the id, but you have to use "html_name" for the name. Sadly I find your answer is worded confusingly given the question.

Comment: This answer did not work for me, and Will's above worked perfectly. I tried them back to back with instant feedback.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation-

> each form field has an ID attribute set to  `id_<field-name>`
> , which is referenced by the accompanying label tag. This is important in ensuring that forms are accessible to assistive technology such as screen reader software. You can also customize the way in which labels and ids are generated.

So I would like to say `id_field-name` , you collect the field name from the model.

Here is the link to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Answer (score 1):

In Django 2 you can retrieve the ID for a specific field using `{{ field.id_for_label }}`

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields).