# Is it possible to pass the dynamic id with django input form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

html generated by django form:

```
<tr>
    <td>Email:</td><td><input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>User:</td><td><input id="id_user" type="text" name="user" maxlength="100" /></td>
</tr>
```

I am using django form.If i see the id of the rendered field ,that is if the field name is `email`,the id generated by django form in html is `id=id_email`,if field name is `user` the id generated would be `id_user` .

My question is,Is any way is their to pass the dynamic id along with the id generated by html,that is i am trying to do like this,for email field `{{object.id}}_email` and so on.

Is it possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763423/how-to-get-form-fields-id-in-django

Comment: @mariodev in form field if i use {{formname.fieldname.suto_id}},in html it is just displaying the id of that field.I want the dynamic id of that form field.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to [style the widget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances).  The docs have [a good example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.id_for_label) of how to do this for an id.

Answer (score -1):

`<p class="main_heading" action='profile_search' name="{{ v.user }}" id="{{ v.user }}">something</p>`