# How to insert django form field attributes into HTML code?

Tags: html, django, templates

I am trying to put {{field.id}} in the the HTML input attributes but it doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.id}}">
```

I also tried:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id={{field.id}}>
```

Heres my full code:

```
{% for field in wizard.form %}


   <div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-4" for={{field.id_for_label}}>{{ field.label }}</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">   


       <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="{{field.id}}">
            {{field.id}}




        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the generated id of a form field like so:

```
{{ field.auto_id }}
```

This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3765016/1637351

Edit:
Though I don't understand why you're trying to put the id value as the name attribute. That will result in the rendered html being

```
<input name="id_field_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be taken care of automatically if using the field template tag.

Instead, I'd try a different approach than you're using, using [django_widget_tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) to programmatically add attributes.

For example, in your template...

```
{% for field in wizard.form %}
   <div class="row">
    <label class="col-xs-4" for={{field.auto_id}}>{{ field.label }}</label>
      <div class="col-xs-2">   
       <div class="form-group">
            {{field|attr:'class:form-control}}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

This will automatically generate the input for each field with `class='form-control'` as part of the tag. The id/name will automatically be taken care of by rendering `field`.