# "placeholder-shown" selector not working with django forms

Tags: django, django-forms

I have input fields that lower label when something has been typed in it.

[image: a]

[image: b]

[paste bin css](https://pastebin.com/Ls0ESSgW)

```
<div class="form__group">
<input type="text" class="form__input" id="name" placeholder="Full name" required=""       
   autocomplete='off' />
<label for="name" class="form__label">Full Name</label>
</div>
```

But, when I use django forms, they don't work at all

[image]

```
<div class="form__group col">
    {{createSet.title}}
    <label for="id_title" class="form__label">Title</label>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you are not able to show placeholder right? if this is the problem you can put placeholder with a lot of methods                                                                            
 1- define placeholder with widget in forms.py                                                                   
 2- or using jquery : $('# id__title').attr (' placeholder ',' title ')  #im not sure about the syntax though

Comment: you can select the id of a form element. check this [https://stackoverflow.com/q/3763423/9630323]