# What is the equivalent of <input id="id"> with Django form

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I am trying to input results from Autocomplete in (a.js file) into a Django form (html).

Currently the html file looks like this:

**Template:**

```
<input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
```

Obvioulsy, I cannot input directly {{form.street_number}}. I have found a few posts on the topic, (in particular this one: [How to get form fields' id in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763423/how-to-get-form-fields-id-in-django)), but I am not too sure to understand how this solves the problem.

**.js file**

```
 function initAutocomplete(){  
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"),{
        componentRestrictions: {'country':['uk']},
        fields: ['name','geometry','address_components'],
        types:['establishment','geocode']
      });
    
       autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress );
    }
    
    function fillInAddress(){
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        //showsdiffrent address components (click on 'inspect' on webpage to see)
        console.log(place);
    
         document.getElementById('business').value = place.name;
            //loop through address components detailed in consol 
            for (let i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
                ...
                if (place.address_components[i].types[j] === "street_number") {
                document.getElementById('street_number').value = place.address_components[i].short_name;
                } ...
```

I suppose the question is how do I translate `<input id="id">` into django form terms? Maybe there is a possibility to apply an id in the django form.py itself?

I tried a solution found on here, but I am getting an error saying TextInput is not defined.

**forms.py:**

```
 class VenueForm(ModelForm):
        address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, widget = forms.HiddenInput())
    
        class Meta:
            model = Venue
            fields = ['address']
        
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                super(VenueForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.fields['address'].widget = TextInput(attrs={
                    'id': 'street_number'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is the solution I worked out.

Reading different posts, there is probably more sophisticated ways to address the problem, but this one worked for me. It might also be more beneficial for other beginners like me, as this solution is easy to understand.

I basically created an id for each form field in the forms.py. Without this id in the forms, django did not make the link between the assigned ID in the .js file and the form field in the template.

**forms.py**

```
class VenueForm(ModelForm):
    street_number = forms.CharField(max_length=100, label = '', widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"street_number"}))
```

**template**

```
 <form id="venueform" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|as_crispy_errors }}

    <td class="label">Street Number </td>
    {{form.street_number| as_crispy_field}} </form>
```

**.js file (not changes)**

```
function initAutocomplete(){  
      autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"),{
        componentRestrictions: {'country':['uk']},
        fields: ['name','geometry','address_components'],
        types:['establishment','geocode']
      });
    
       autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress );
    }
    
    function fillInAddress(){
        // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        //showsdiffrent address components (click on 'inspect' on webpage to see)
        console.log(place);
    
         document.getElementById('business').value = place.name;
            //loop through address components detailed in consol 
            for (let i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
              for (let j = 0; j < place.address_components[i].types.length; j++) {
                ...
                if (place.address_components[i].types[j] === "street_number") {
                document.getElementById('street_number').value = place.address_components[i].short_name;
                } ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using `id` wrong:

```
<input class="field" name="my_test_name" value="my_test_value" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
```

in this example above:

`id` works for your `html`, `css`, and `javascript` `to identify` this particular `input`. You dont need `id` atribute with django, only with frontend.

In case you want to `recieve data in django`, for example you use this input in a form with POST request, you can identify this input via `name`, and `recieve` its `value` (from value atribute)

```
def my_function_name(request):
    my_value = request.POST['my_test_name']
    print(my_value)
    #output will be >> my_test_value
```

Also you don't need to override your `ModelForm`, you can add this `input` below your form, and it will be working

Comment: I understand from your answer, I need to drop the idea of giving an ID in the ModelForm. I am however unclear with what I should connect "document.getElementById" from the .js file to the template, in order for django understand that the form field "address" is equal to "getElementById('street_number').value", considering that the only thing I can enter in the template is {{form.address}}. I am hoping I am making sense! (thanks for the help!)