# Get formset name variables in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I am sending a formset to my template. I want to add some style to it, so I need to access his variables.
I took the following code from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/forms/formsets/#using-initial-data-with-a-formset), where they print the form and it has some attributes, amongside them the **name="form-0-title"**.

```
for form in formset:
    print(form.as_table())

<tr><th><label for="id_form-0-title">Title:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="form-0-title" value="Django is now open source" id="id_form-0-title"></td></tr>
...
```

As I want to style my forms, I need to give the inputs a name to know how to treat them in the backend. When I do the following in the templates

```
{{ proficiency_form.management_form }}
{% for form in proficiency_form %}
    {{form.title.name}}
{% endfor %}
```

I get **title, title, ...** instead of **id_form-0-title, id_form-1-title, ...**
How can I get the correct name in the templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the input's name of your fields like so:

```
{{ proficiency_form.management_form }}
{% for form in proficiency_form %}
    {{form.title.html_name}}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to get the label's id, you can consider this approach:

```
{{ proficiency_form.management_form }}
{% for form in proficiency_form %}
    {{form.title.id_for_label}}
{% endfor %}
```

Read more about it in the official [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#:%7E:text=%7B%7B%20field.html_name%20%7D%7D).

You can find a similar(almost duplicate) question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763423/how-to-get-form-fields-id-in-django).